# Android ip discovery on wifi

Tags: android, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

I'm designing an android app in order to communicate with other phones. After a lot of tries I tested that broadcast and/or multicast transmission (via UDP) is totally unreliable when the screen is off. Even taking a wakelock and a wifilock. 
Unicast with TCP, instead, seems much better. In order to connect to the *other* device, however, I need to know the remote IP address of it.

How can I achieve this? Is there any form of DNS? I need an association among a name and its IP address.

Comment: I want the other device ip, I well know how get my ip.....

Comment: I would like an answer to this question too.